# Can my Google App receive Traffic from Single IP address

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to host an SMS application on GAE  and all my traffic will come
from a  SMS GATEWAY with a single IP address.
Is that fine(I'm expecting 500 dynamic requests/sec) ?
Will there be any problems like unusual traffic errors or any other issues ?

**EDITED**

More info:
My users send queries through SMS which will be routed to my app from SMS GATEWAY(single IP address).
My app processes those queries and reply back through SMS (again through SMS GATEWAY).
I can reply using URL FETCH(not a problem) but what i'm worried about is if I receive some 500 dynamic requests/sec from single IP address , GAE might block them thinking them as Dos(denial of service) attack .

GAE either asks the user to enter a captcha at https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha or redirects to sorry.google.com and displays an error message itseems if it receives unusual traffic  from single IP . But my users access app only through SMS.

Please look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5239&q=dos&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) production issue filed.

Answer (score 1):

It would be technically doable - your app can detect the user's IP via the `REMOTE_ADDR` environment variable, and if it's the one you want, show them the actual page (showing them a 403 otherwise). Your second question is a bit trickier to answer - your App Engine app could handle it assuming you wrote it in a scalable manner (not a trivial assumption!) and if you can afford the amount of traffic you're trying to throw at it.

Comment: hi Cris. What i want to ask is if an app receives high traffic(may be dynamic requests 500/sec) from single IP address will GAE allow them or block them thinking as denial of service attack(Dos) ?

Comment: GAE does not block, Dos is regulated by you using the [DOS Protection service](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/java/config/dos.html).

Comment: @systempuntoout please look at this production issue filed :

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5239&q=dos&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be concerned that getting that level of traffic from a single IP might set off some form of DoS protection - it shouldn't, but it's impossible to rule it out. If it were to happen, you could [file a production issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue), and we'd take care of it.

Comment: please look at this production issue filed :

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5239&q=dos&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Comment: Um, you need to file a (new) production issue if you actually experience this issue, so we can fix it - not ahead of time on the off-chance.